# How to pass values from one page to another by onclick in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
1Page.js

function TableRow() {
        let cells = document.querySelectorAll('#recieve-info td');
        cells.forEach(cell => cell.onclick = function () {
            let prevcell = cell.previousElementSibling;
            if (prevcell) {
    
                let LSItems;
                let AddValue = '/images/back_arrow.png.png'
    
                if (localStorage.getItem('passvalue') === null) {
                    LSItems = [];
                } else {
                    LSItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('passvalue'));
                }
                
                LSItems.push([AddValue]);
                localStorage.setItem('passvalue', JSON.stringify(LSItems));
                let prev = prevcell.innerHTML;
                console.log(prev);
            }
        });
    }
```

I am trying to pass values by onclick, like if i click on the first one which is 'Save1' i want to save my value only in the first one.

[image: This is my first page]

2Page.js

```
function ParaG() {
  document.querySelector('.Second-Para').innerHTML = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('passvalue'));
}
```

Here i want the values.

[image: This is second page output]

Comment: With just JavaScript? No database or something? You can store the data in the local storage https://javascript.info/localstorage

Comment: The best way to transfer information from one page to another is with a SESSION variable on the server side

Comment: @DeepakRandhawa does my answer fix your question, if it does can you accept it (click checkmark)

Comment: @DeepakRadhawa, is there any reason you unaccepted my answer?

Comment: @KetZoomer Because it continuously saves in all of list item, not in which i want to save

Comment: you save the cookie, and access it in another page, that has nothing to do with a list

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookies.

You can save the cookie:

```
document.cookie = "option=Option1";
```

And get the cookie:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
console.log(getCookie("option"))
```

https://w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp